# Recursive function to get a multidimensional array of subdirectories

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

So, I literally spent two days trying to get this into my head. I want a function that creates a multidimensional array from a dirtree. I did it manually before and got this result:

```
Array ()

    [cats] = Array()
        [domestic] = Array ()
        [wild] = Array ()

    [dogs] = Array ()
        [big] = Array ()
        [small] = Array ()

    [emptyfolder]
```

By manually I mean doing something like this within my function: `$result['level1']['level2'] = array();` This doesn't work well because I don't know the depth of the dirtree beforehand.

The function also uses another function `GetSubdirectories($directory)` which returns and array like this:

```
[0] = 'cats',
[1] = 'dogs'
[2] = 'emptyfolder'
```

So, here is the function in question:

```
<?php
public function GetStructure($directory, $node = 'content') //the root folder is content
    {
        if (!isset($structure))
            {
            $structure = array();
            }

        $subdirectories = $this->GetSubdirectories($directory);
        if (is_array($subdirectories))
            {
            foreach ($subdirectories as $subdirectory)
                {
                    //add new subarray
                    $structure[$node] = array();
                    //set the current path
                    $currentDirectory = $directory . "/" . $subdirectory;
                    //repeat
                    $this->GetStructure(); // <-- how to I call the function?
                }
            }
        return $structure;
        }
?>
```

From what I understand, the problem is "telling the function where to put the next arrays". I just don't get it and any help would be much appreciated!

**SOLUTION**

```
<?php
public function PopulateArrayWithDirtree($dir, &$array = false)
    {
    $subDirs = $this->GetSubdirectories($dir);
    if (is_array($subDirs))
        {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($subDirs); $i++)
            {
            $array[$subDirs[$i]] = array();
            $this->PopulateArrayWithDirtree(($dir . "/" . $subDirs[$i]), $array[$subDirs[$i]]); //repeat
            }
        }
    return true;
    }

public function Test()
    {
    $path = $this->contentpath;
    $structure = array();
    $this->PopulateArrayWithDirtree($path, $structure);
    print_r($structure);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to access the next element?

Don't use a `foreach`, but a `for` loop:

```
$keys = arraykeys($subdirectories);
$length = sizeof($keys);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    $structure[$node] = array();
    $currentDirectory = $directory . "/" . $subdirectory;
    $this->GetStructure($subdirectories[$i]);

}
```

however, if you mean set the result, then this may be it. I'm still confused:

```
$keys = arraykeys($subdirectories);
$length = sizeof($keys);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
    $currentDirectory = $directory . "/" . $subdirectory;
    $structure[$node] = $this->GetStructure($subdirectories[$i]);
}
```

Comment: alright, you got me on the right path. see edit for solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
$this->GetStructure(); // <-- how to I call the function?
```

to:

```
GetStructure($currentDirectory);
```